# Make radio buttons replaced with images in same line

Tags: css, image, radio-button

```
.form-group {
    height: 16px;
}

.form-group > input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

.form-group > input + label {
    background-image: url('Empty_Star.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    display:block;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:16px;
}
.form-group > input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

<form name="rating" class="form-group">
        <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="rate" value="1"/>
        <label for="radio1"></label>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="rate" value="2"/>
        <label for="radio2"></label>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="rate" value="3"/>
        <label for="radio3"></label>
        <input id="radio4" type="radio" name="rate" value="4"/>
        <label for="radio4"></label>
        <input id="radio5" type="radio" name="rate" value="5"/>
        <label for="radio5"></label>
</form>
```

I don't need the labels there, but EVERY tutorial on how to replace radio buttons included them and disincluding them didn't work.  So any help with that is appreciated as well.  But my main problem is getting each of the five stars (the images) side by side each other.  No matter what I do it doesn't work.  I've tried playing with the display options and reading other tutorials.  Nothing is working properly.  Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-group {
   /* height: 16px;*/
}
.form-group ul{}
.form-group ul li{    
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.form-group  input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}

.form-group  input[type="radio"] + label {
    background-image: url('http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/uidesignicons/16x16/star_full.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    display:block;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:16px;
}
.form-group input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    /*background-position: 0 0;*/
    background: url(http://www.iconsearch.ru/ajax/download.php?icon_id=14617&size=1&format=ico);
}
label{
    display: block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<form name="rating" class="form-group">
        <ul>
       <li><input id="radio1" type="radio" name="rate1" value="1"/>
        <label for="radio1"></label>
        <li><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="rate2" value="2"/>
        <label for="radio2"></label>
        <li><input id="radio3" type="radio" name="rate3" value="3"/>
        <label for="radio3"></label>
        <li><input id="radio4" type="radio" name="rate4" value="4"/>
        <label for="radio4"></label>
        <li><input id="radio5" type="radio" name="rate5" value="5"/>
        <label for="radio5"></label>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Running the code snippet works and I like it, but is it an easy task so that all the stars preceding the one selected is gold?  If star 3 is selected (on hover and click), 1 through 3 will be gold.  I also need to have the radio buttons submit the form on click.  I'm sure you can guess the purpose of that.  But I have a tutorial on it, so I'll look there for that.  Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!

Comment: You did an excellent job, but I think there's another issue in my styling or parent elements.  There's still only one star per line.  I'll try to find conflicts in the stylesheet.

Comment: @Donald link url site?

Comment: You would have to register to gain access.  It's at next-factor.com... however, I got it working just like the snippet above.

Comment: @Donald - that it was possible to choose more than one star is necessary that was different name for input. See updated response